# What is sharedSecret in JWT

Tags: jwt, silhouette

In `Silhouette`, a JWT authenticator could be created using the following class

```
JWTAuthenticatorSettings(fieldName: String = "X-Auth-Token", requestParts: Option[Seq[api.util.RequestPart.Value]] = Some(Seq(RequestPart.Headers)), issuerClaim: String = "play-silhouette", authenticatorIdleTimeout: Option[FiniteDuration] = None, authenticatorExpiry: FiniteDuration = 12 hours, sharedSecret: String)
```

What is the use of `sharedSecret`? Is it what the application would use when signing the JWT header/claims payload?

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  sharedSecret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the formula it looks like `sharedSecret` should be just `secret`. This is important since it **should not be shared** with clients. Usually, there is only one `secret` parameter (or several) that is used for all clients. Maybe in this sense, it is shared.

Comment: In the HS256 scheme for JWT, the secret _is_ shared between the client (creating the JWT) and the server (verifying the JWT).

You can use the same secret for each client, but then a given client could impersonate another client. Whether you care depends on your threat model.

In the RS256 scheme, which uses asymmetric keys, the client signs the JWT with its private key, and the server verifies it with that client's public key.

Again, you could (but probably shouldn't) use the same keypair for more than one client.